# $(z+\bar z)|w|^2 - (z-\bar z)|w|i - 2(z + \bar z) = 0 $

Tags: complex-numbers

I  have the following equation:

$$(z+\bar z)|w|^2 - (z-\bar z)|w|i - 2(z + \bar z) = 0. $$

I need to show that $z$ can't be an imaginary number.

then that the image of $z$ passes from (0,0)

Comment: by $z^*$ do you mean the complex conjugate? then it is better to use $\bar z$

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By rearranging you equation, we get
$$(z+\bar z)|w|^2 - 2(z + \bar z) = (z-\bar z)|w|i$$
Do you know that $z+\bar z=2\Re(z)$ and $z-\bar z=2i\Im(z)$ - if you never seen this before, prove it by setting $z=x+iy$ and computing directly. So you have:
$$2(|w|^2-2)\Re(z)=-2|w|\Im(z)$$
What happens if $z$ is imaginary?